# Python: Avoiding overwriting/unreadability of columns while writing a csv file

Tags: python, csv, tabs, file-writing

In Python 2.7, I am attempting to write a `csv` file along these lines:

```
#do stuff
import csv
with open(newpath1+'\\stats_matrix_LATTICE_NETWORK.csv', 'wb') as f: #Change file name as needed
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter='\t', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
    writer.writerows(stats_matrix) #stats_matrix is my list with the values
```

I get a visualization exactly like this:

```
dict1   dict2   dict3   dict4   dict5   dict6   dict7   dict8
8904    89.04   1096    10.959999999999994  39  0.39    8943    89.43   1057    99.61   8943    89.43   1057    10.57   1014    1014    0.0 3.7369914853358561
9358    93.58   642 6.420000000000002   43  0.43    9401    94.01   599 99.57   9401    94.01   599 5.99    0   0   0   0.0
9600    96.0    400 4.0 13  0.13    9613    96.13   387 99.87   9613    96.13   387 3.87    0   0   0   0.0
7595    75.95   2405    24.049999999999997  70  0.7 7665    76.65   2335    99.3    7665    76.65   2335    23.35   0   0   0   0.0
```

Although I use `delimiter='\t'`, my columns are not readable. **Is there a way for me to put additional `tabs` in order to more efficiently separate columns?**

Comment: How are you getting a visual?  Would you be able to use something like Excel or Google Sheets to view the content as well as provide formatting of the data such that you wouldn't need to insert extra tab characters

Comment: What do you mean by "how are you getting a visual"? I simply get a `csv` file and open it with Notepad. It would be much more helpful for me to be able to read values without them overlapping each other...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on which editor you use to view your file, you will see it displayed differently depending on how it handles tabs.

Rather than trying to use CSV format (comma separated variables), why not pad your columns using spaces? After all, notepad is designed to view text files. As long as each of your rows contain the same number of columns, the following function could be used to automatically align each of the columns:

```
data = [
    ["dict1", "dict2", "dict3", "dict4", "dict5", "dict6", "dict7", "dict8", "dict9", "dict10", "dict11", "dict12", "dict13", "dict14", "dict15", "dict16", "dict17", "dict18"],
    ["8904", "89.04", "1096", "10.959999999999994", "39", "0.39", "8943", "89.43", "1057", "99.61", "8943", "89.43", "1057", "10.57", "1014", "1014", "0.0", "3.7369914853358561"],
    ["9358", "93.58", "642", "6.420000000000002", "43", "0.43", "9401", "94.01", "599", "99.57", "9401", "94.01", "599", "5.99", "0", "0", "0", "0.0"],
    ["9600", "96.0", "400", "4.0", "13", "0.13", "9613", "96.13", "387", "99.87", "9613", "96.13", "387", "3.87", "0", "0", "0", "0.0"],
    ["7595", "75.95", "2405", "24.049999999999997", "70", "0.7", "7665", "76.65", "2335", "99.3", "7665", "76.65", "2335", "23.35", "0", "0", "0", "0.0"],
]

def write_cols(filename, data):
    widths = [0] * len(data[0])

    for row in data:
        widths[:] = [max(widths[index], len(str(col))) for index, col in enumerate(row)]

    with open(filename, 'w') as f_output:
        for row in data:
            f_output.write("  ".join("%-*s" % (widths[index], col) for index, col in enumerate(row)) + '\n')

write_cols('output.txt', data)
```

For your data, it would be written to a text file which will display as follows in notepad:

```
dict1  dict2  dict3  dict4               dict5  dict6  dict7  dict8  dict9  dict10  dict11  dict12  dict13  dict14  dict15  dict16  dict17  dict18            
8904   89.04  1096   10.959999999999994  39     0.39   8943   89.43  1057   99.61   8943    89.43   1057    10.57   1014    1014    0.0     3.7369914853358561
9358   93.58  642    6.420000000000002   43     0.43   9401   94.01  599    99.57   9401    94.01   599     5.99    0       0       0       0.0               
9600   96.0   400    4.0                 13     0.13   9613   96.13  387    99.87   9613    96.13   387     3.87    0       0       0       0.0               
7595   75.95  2405   24.049999999999997  70     0.7    7665   76.65  2335   99.3    7665    76.65   2335    23.35   0       0       0       0.0
```

This assumes your editor uses a fixed width font.